# QSerialPort cannot open with error code 11

Tags: c++, c, qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I'm trying to communicate with a device which provided a serial port. When I use the example C program provided by the device producer, it was successfully connected and I can send/receive data. But when I use my C++ program with `QSerialPort`, the `open()` method returned `false` and the `error()` returned `11` (An unidentified error occurred, as described by [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#SerialPortError-enum)). Could anyone please help me?

- OS: Cent OS 6.9
- gcc/g++: 4.8
- Qt: 5.6.0

---

An example of connecting with `QSerialPort`:

```
#include <qserialport.h>
#include <qstring.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    QString portName = "/dev/corser/x64ExpCL4x1_s0";
    QSerialPort *pSerial = new QSerialPort();
    pSerial->setPortName(portName);
    pSerial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    pSerial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    pSerial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    pSerial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    pSerial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    bool success = pSerial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    if (!success) {
        printf("Error: %d\n", pSerial->error());
    } else {
        printf("Success.\n");
        pSerial->close();
    }
    delete pSerial;
    return 0;
}
```

This program prints out `Error: 11`.

---

Here is a C program which is excerpted from the device's example program. This program just try to connect the serial port and then close the connection. While the original example program is complicated. It is actually kind of a "Terminal" program which sends user-input commands to the device and prints out the responses from the device.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <ctype.h>          /* Character types */


#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct 
{
    int     open;           // Flag for current open status of port 
    int     update;         // Flag indicating parameter changes    
    char    *port;          // Current port to be opened            
    int     iod;            // I/O index for open device port       
    struct  termios stty;   // Terminal port control structure      
} SCOM_CTL;

struct termios ttctl = {0};
struct termios ttsav = {0};
struct termios coctl = {0};
struct termios cnctl = {0};

#define OPEN            1
#define CLOSE           2
#define UPDATE          3
#define NO_UPDATE       4

SCOM_CTL scom;

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    scom.port = "/dev/corser/x64ExpCL4x1_s0";
    scom_init();
    scom_open_port();

    if (scom.open == OPEN) 
    { 
        fputs("\rSuccess.\r\n", stdout);
        scom_close_port(scom.iod);
    }
    else
    {
        fputs("\rError.\r\n", stdout);
    }
}

// Initialize the console (stdin) for raw access.
int scom_init()
{
    int i;
    scom.open = CLOSE;
    scom.update = NO_UPDATE;
    scom.iod  = -1;
    tcgetattr(0, &coctl);   // Save a copy to restore stdin.
    tcgetattr(0, &cnctl);
    cfmakeraw( &cnctl);     // Set stdin to raw !
    tcsetattr(0, 0, &cnctl);    
}

int scom_open_port()
{
    int i, iod;

    if (scom.open == OPEN) 
    {
        close(scom.iod);
        scom.open = CLOSE;
    }

    if ( (iod = open( scom.port, (O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY))) == -1) 
    {
        conres();       /* Reset the console. */
        fputs("term : Open Failure on device\n", stdout);
        return -1;  
    }

    scom.iod = iod;
    scom.open = OPEN;
    scom.update = NO_UPDATE;
}

int scom_close_port()
{
    scom.open = CLOSE;
    close(scom.iod);
}

int conres()
{
    return(tcsetattr(0, 0, &coctl));
}
```

This program prints out `Success.`

Comment: Undefined Error? Not very helpful. To get a clue, may be, this could help: Assuming that Qt uses underlying OS functions, it could be worth to inspect `errno` with `strerror()`. I must admit that I haven't any experience with serial communication and I wouldn't call it a productive solution. If in doubt, you could inspect Qt sources on github or woboq to find out what happens under the hood...

Comment: QSerialPort::open() function return false if opening the port is successful, but could not set any of the port settings successfully. Did you try to set the port speed or other settings in your C code ?